# How to pass overloaded nonmember functions to threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
void foo(int n){cout << n << '\n';}

void foo(string s){cout << s << '\n';}

int main(){
    thread t1{foo,9};
    thread t2{foo,"nine"};
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error

no matching function for call to std::thread::thread brace-enclosed initializer list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#Notes) to disambiguate them:

> static_cast may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type, as in std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), static_cast(std::toupper));

```
thread t1{static_cast<void(*)(int)>(foo),9};
thread t2{static_cast<void(*)(string)>(foo),"nine"};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a cast in order to select the desired overload function.

Here is a working code for doing it:

```
void foo(int n){cout << n << '\n';}

void foo(string s){cout << s << '\n';}

int main(){
    void (*foo1)(int) = foo;
    void (*foo2)(string) = foo;
    thread t1(foo1,9);
    thread t2(foo2,"nine");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use lambda functions for simplicity and readability:

```
thread t1([]{foo(9); });
thread t2([]{foo("str");});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may C-style cast it directly:

```
thread t1{(void (*)(int))foo,9};
thread t2{(void (*)(string))foo,"nine"};
```

Comment: Unless you need to cast to a private base, you really are better using c++ styled casts in c++ code.

Comment: Okay, `thread t1{static_cast<void (*)(int)>(foo),9}; t2{static_cast<void (*)(string)>(foo),"nine"};`, but it's longer.